# How can my Node.js server inside a Docker container get the remoteAddress of connecting clients?

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose

What's happening now is that `req.socket.remoteAddress` is always returning `172.23.0.1` or the like — the IP address of the Docker bridge, not the actual remote address of the client accessing my server. That part of this problem I've found a lot of people, not just myself, have struggled with.

There are no request headers like `x-real-ip` or `x-forwarded-for` available I can use as an alternative.

I've seen some solutions which pertain to a Node.js server running inside nginx, but I have no such extra wrapper around my server. I'm running an Express server by itself.

Here's a stripped-down version of my `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: "3.1"

networks:
  lan_access:
    driver: bridge # Tried changing this to "host", didn't help.

volumes:
  # Set up a couple of volumes, not relevant to this question.

services:
  nodejs:
    image: node:18
    # network_mode: "host" <-- Tried this suggestion, couldn't reach server afterward.
    # extra_hosts: <-- Tried this suggestion, no obvious effect.
    #  - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"
    environment:
      # A bunch of environment variables not relevant to this question.
    ports:
      - "8000:8000" # Receives router redirect from WAN:443
      - "8080:8080" # Receives router redirect from WAN:80
    working_dir: /home/app
    restart: always
    volumes:
      # Blah, blah
    command: ["node", "app.js"]
```

I'd be fine with this container directly binding to host system ports, which is what I gather `network_mode: "host"` is supposed to do, but when I tried this no outside connections reached my server at all.

Any suggestions?

**Update:**

It appears that `network_mode: "host"` only works for Linux hosts. I'm using Docker Desktop on Windows. No error message is produced, but my app is, without complaint, cut off from being accessed when `network_mode: "host"` is used.

I'm beginning to wonder if seeing client IP addresses is even possible when using Docker on Windows.

**Update 2:**

This doesn't solve the question I was asking here, but since I don't really need Docker yet for anything else, I'm just running my Node.js app on its own for now. No problem seeing the remote IP address that way.